# Android Studio: Font family is red for some reason?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm currently working on a rock paper scissors project on Android Studio and did play around with the font a little bit. However, during the program editing, I noticed that my font folder had a red underline on it, indicating an error. The error was: "The font ".xml" in font has no declaration in the base font folder; this can lead to crashes when the resource is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier".

[image]

I thought I could fix it real quick by doing an Alt+Enter but that did not do anything, so I want to know how I can fix this error.

Thank you in advance.

As stated below, all I actually had to do was set a name to it. After that, I rebuilt it and it worked well.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this file just doesn't have a name, which further will be the id of font in `Resources`. probably thats why file is underlined, just set some name for it and rebuild project (for rebuilding resources references)